# Trouble using 'foreach' with a generic list

Tags: c#, list, foreach, generics

I have not until now tried to use a foreach clause in a generic list. The compile error I get is:

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DMS.OrderNodeList' because 'DMS.OrderNodeList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Any suggestions what to do next?

Thanks,

Comment: OrderNodeList does not seem to implement any of the enumerable interfaces? IEnumerable, IList, IList<T> etc. Hence, it is *not* a generic list - as far as .NET is concerned, it is not a list at all. Regarding "Any suggestions what to do next" - yes, read up on lists and generics in .NET. Specifically, take the time to learn about IEnumerable and IEnumerable<T> and what they mean.

Comment: Google is unable to find *anything* on “DMS.OrderNodeList”. How is it defined?

Comment: konrad. nice. subtle. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) interface in your **custom** collection (*it is not a generic list*).

Comment: If it exposes IEnumerable a .ToList().ForEach() would be an option.... I think you mean he has to explicitly implement IEnumerable<>, no?

Comment: @Sky The irony being that the IEnumerable<T> interface does not actually have ForEach() as a member. Alas, the original post uses the word "generic" in a vague fashion, so we don't know if the list needs to be generic (IEnumerable<T>) or if it's "generic" in that it holds misc. things.

If he just needs ForEach(), then IEnumerable is what he needs, IEnumerable<T> doesn't force an implementation.

Comment: I hear ya. Guess we will have to wait for the beta release of DMS.OrderNodeList to find out.

Comment: @Sky I've signed up for the invite-only beta of DMS.OrderNodeList on their secret Facebook page. Yay! Can't wait.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your `OrderNodeList` class to extend `Collection<OrderNode>`, then you'll get this enumerator in for you (and probably much of the logic you've created manually to manage the collection will now be implemented for you.)

This is assuming that your `OrderNodeList` holds a collection of `OrderNode` objects.

Comment: Collection of Lists, are you sure? Should it not be extending Collection<OrderNode>